# How redirect a jwt login request?

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, redirect, jwt

I have an ionic app with JWT authentication. Now I'm planning to move the API from `api.example.com` to `example.com/api`. I tried moving everything and setup 301 redirects on `api.example.com` to `example.com/api` and almost everything works. Only thing what didn't work was the JWT login. Does this have something to do with the 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' in the `.htaccess` file. Or is this completely impossible?

It is important that the old apps with `api.example.com` still work after I move the API.

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirecting POST requests (for the login) then you will need to use a 308 ("permanent redirect") status in order to preserve the POST request method. When the browser receives a 301 ("moved permanently") status then it will likely issue a GET, rather than POST, request method for the redirected request.